# Uninstalling R and R Studio from the mac

Tags: macos, r

How to delete R from the mac. Currently, Tidyverse package no longer works and thus I have to reinstall the R. But, I am not able to fully delete the programme as it keeps creeping back. What to do to completely uninstall R and R Studio from the mac.

I can’t locate a script to remove all the things these packages installed nor able to find support from the R community.

Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: How did you install it in the first place, and from where? Did it come with an uninstaller? Does https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554736-How-To-Uninstall-RStudio-Desktop help?

Comment: I installed it form r project. Now when I run tidyverse package it gives this info below. Thats why I wanted to complete delete it and reinstall it: > library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘fs’

Comment: Please focus the question on either the deinstall *or* the tidyverse issues.

Comment: Question is really simple and it is here .. How to uninstall r from Mac?

Answer (score 1):

From https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html:

> 1.3 How can R for Mac OS X be obtained and installed?
>
> [...]
>
> Further details, including uninstallation and building R from the sources, are in the ‘R Installation and Administration Manual’.

Said manual is at https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html.